# Every clicked thumbnail should slide to the left, not just the first image

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

hi guys need your help in this,

**Expected Result:** All image should repeat the slide animation from right to left each time a thumbnail is clicked.

**Current Result:** As of now, the first image is the only that performs the slide animation.

Here's my jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/30ypzk9y/3/

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.thumbnail-stay a', function(){

        var photo_fullsize =  jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('150/200','500/500');

        jQuery('.gallery-main-img img').attr('src', photo_fullsize).attr('style', '-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; animation-fill-mode: forwards;').addClass('gallery-main-img-move')
        // .delay(1000)
        // .queue(function() {
        //  $(this).removeClass("gallery-main-img-move");
        //  $(this).dequeue();
        // });
        // .attr('style', 'right:0;');

        return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you want each image to slide in from right to left when clicked. You are accomplishing this by:

1. Each time an image is clicked, you are updating the main image (the one that slides) so that the src attr reflects that of the clicked image.
2. You are then adding the slide animation.

The issue I see is, you are not moving the image back to the original starting point before animating it, so once you click the second image, the image is already in the ending position. You need to move the image back on each click so that it can animate over.